# Magento 2.X How to keep the payment in pending when a new order is created

Tags: orders, magento2.3, payment

Current situation. When a new order is created, the status is changed to processing and the payment is completed.
What I want to change. After a new order is created, the status is changed to processing, but the payment is kept in pending until someone manually verifies the order. After everything is ok, change the status to completed and payment is completed.

Comment: You using online payment method ?

Comment: I am using pronko converge payment plugin

Comment: and it captures payment directly from card,bank account right ?

Answer (score 0):

If you select “Authorize and Capture (Sale)” for Payment Action option in the payment configuration, the initial order payment transaction will transfer a payment amount directly to a merchant bank account and you need not to capture it manually from the orders.

If you select “Authorize” for Payment Action option in the payment configuration then you need to capture the payment manually from the orders.